# "Speak a first language" vs. "speak in a first language"

Tags: prepositions

I though that *speak in a first language* was incorrect, but in one of his books Scott Thurnbury, namely How To Teach Speaking, uses the preposition *in* in there. Here is the passage:

> Of course, the knowledge base for **speaking in a first language** is largely intuitive: it's not something a person is normally sufficiently aware of to be able to describe.

What is the difference between *speak a first language* and *speak in a first language*?

Comment: To speak in Russian, to speak in Chinese, to speak in French, to speak in a second language, etc. versus To speak Russian, to speak Chinese, to speak French, to speak a second language...You can know how to speak some language and not be speaking in it.  When I arrived at the event, the speaker was speaking in French.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comment! Is it possible to use "in" with accent? For example: I can speak in a British accent"?

Comment: Sure, or with a British accent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To speak in Russian, to speak in Chinese, to speak in French, to speak in a second language, etc. versus To speak Russian, to speak Chinese, to speak French, to speak a second language...

**You can know how to speak some language and not be speaking in it.** For example, "When I arrived at the event, the speaker was speaking in French".   However, we can also say: "When I arrived at the event, the speaker was speaking French, not Italian".

- to speak in a British accent or with a British accent.